# Procedimiento Almacenado Mariadb 10.1 asignacion variables

Tags: mariadb

tengo un procedimiento Almacenado funciona de maravilla... pero deseo optimizarlo.. lo que necesito es declarar un variable, asignar a esa variable un valor de un campo de una tabla...
pero el simple hecho de hacer cualquier cambio en dicho procedimiento me arroja un error 1064

--------  mas o menos asi es lo que quiero implemetar

```
declare alf int ;
set alf = (SELECT configurar.dias_vaca from configurar)

despues viene el 

select *****  

en el cual deseo introducir la variable Alf

****
he probado con:
delimiter
begin .. end
```

y nada  por cierto uso:

> mariadb 10.1.21   phpmyadmin  4.6.5.2

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es:

```sql
MariaDB [test]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 10.3.10   |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [test]> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `alf` INT DEFAULT (
    ->     SELECT `configurar`.`dias_vaca`
    ->     FROM (SELECT 5 `dias_vaca`) `configurar`
    ->   );
    ->   SELECT `alf`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [test]> CALL `sp_test`;
+-------+
| `alf` |
+-------+
|     5 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```